# Why is my random forest model only predicting one class?

Tags: r, machine-learning, random-forest

The random forest model is simply voting the response variable to be one class and the error rate is 19.22%. The rate is impressive, but I'm just wondering how I can make the model favor the second row and column more? Thanks.

```
randomForest(formula = y1 ~ . - y1, data = df1, ntree = 20000) 
           Type of random forest: classification
                 Number of trees: 20000
No. of variables tried at each split: 7

    OOB estimate of  error rate: 19.22%
Confusion matrix:
     0 1 class.error
0 5219 0           0
1 1242 0           1
```

Comment: This usually happens when your classes are highly skewed. Look into methods for handling class skew. Undersampling and oversampling are two straightforward approaches.

Comment: This is *not* a heavily skewed sample. From the confusion matrix we see that we have ~1.24K positive samples out of a total ~6.46K item sample; 19.2% positives while clearly imbalanced is far from "heavily skewed". A much more plausible issue is having substantial overlap between classes in the feature space explored.

Comment: It looks like your confusion matrix is based on an arbitrary threashold of 0.5. You need to put work into tuning your threshold. Your class imbalance is not an issue.

Comment: To definitively answer this, we will need more information (along the lines of the comments).

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you've got a high base rate (high accuracy if you just predict the same answer). In addition to under/oversampling, because you have binary outcomes, I'd suggest looking into the [Matthews Correlation Coefficient](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matthews_correlation_coefficient) for evaluating your model's performance. It's a well-known metric for imbalanced classes.